# openerp7.0 the attribute attrs of button goes the field cannot be found

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I want to realize the button on the current logon were not visible:

```
<group attrs="{'invisible': [('shenqr.user_id','=', uid)]}">
    <button string="prove" name="fjj_action_prove" states="wait_prove"                           
    groups="qingjia.group_assistant_depmanager" />
</group>
```

but it says the field shenqr.user_id cannot be found

while i use like this:

```
  <field name="domain">[('shenqr.user_id','&lt;&gt;',uid)]</field>
```

it works.

what is the problems

Answer (score 0):

You could not get it works in attrs, because it does not support. To make such things, you need to add fields on the current model

In attrs you can only pass OpenERP basic domain.

The domain is parsed by the Web client. That force you to have all fields used in domain in the view event if not shown, they must be invisible fields.

The domain value must be static.

```
attrs="{'readonly': [('my_filed_must_be_in_view', '=', 'static_value')]}"
```

You can not use complex function, or server related code the scope is limited to the view.

**Domain**

Normaly when you add a domain on a field using view definition you can use any kind of standard domain condition.

```
[('invoice.partner_id.name', '=', True)]
```

But you have to consider your self outside of system. It means you can only do domain that will work trough an XMLRPC call.

In the domain value you can use any static value or any field value. Once again if you want to use a field that is not shown as a value, it must be present in view even if invisible.

I do not think you can use context in domain value like in ir.action domain but I will not be categoric.

Regards

Comment: thank you for your ideas ,but i thought it may be cause field redundancy or dababase redundancy